# Page to show a link to every file in an directory

Tags: links, filesystem

I have a file on my server with a large number of PDF files in it (more than 100) and I wish to have a page on WordPress that shows a link to each of these files (say sorted alphabetically by the name of the file). I obviously don't want to have to do this manually.

Additionally the files here change frequently so it would have to be able to check for any changes. I am yet to find a plugin that is able to do this.

Any ideas? I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: I dont think any plugin can help you. You need to simple put all links by create new page from wp admin. Also as far as I know all link will start from your domain name , right? like www.domain.com/abc.pdf so how you need sorting?

Comment: Yes sort of, I have a folder named resources in the wp-content file on the server named resources and I wish to have a page on my wordpress website "Resources" where it displays a link to each file. So it would be domain.com/resources/pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this plugins else you can even create a page with all pdf link to download it.

- [Google Sitemap Generator](https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/google-sitemap-generator)
- [Sitetree](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sitetree/)

Comment: is that plugin gives facility to sort?

Comment: @helping hands Sorting is very simple code so ther is no use of plugin for it

Comment: @HelpingHands please accept the answer if you feel it is usefull